# Laravel routes not working in nginx Ubuntu 16

Tags: laravel, nginx, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, laravel-5.5

I installed laravel project on Google cloud platform.
Every thing fine,running properly,but only index route running when I try to access other route i.e www.domain.com/testing
It show error 404

Here is my default config file
[image]

Comment: What is the value of root(project path)?

Comment: Show your routes code

Comment: whats your document root?

Comment: Document root : /var/www/html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your document root to

`Document root : laravelprojectroot/public`

Answer (score 0):

here is my route file image. Just know I created project on Google cloud platform using nginx and Ubuntu 16
[image]

Comment: Try https://gist.github.com/santoshachari/87bf77baeb45a65eb83b553aceb135a3 this gist for installation

Comment: Every thing in running fine

Comment: Everything is fine? What about testing route?

Comment: whats your document root ?